# Approaches for handling nvarchar sources to data warehouse

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, etl

Situation is this...our data warehouse doesn't need nvarchar and is built using all non-unicode datatypes.  But all new source systems are all coming in with unicode (utf8 Oracle or nvarchar in sqlserver).

If we leave the source nvarchar to our staging then we get implicit datatype conversions if we have to join or compare to our EDW during loads. Plus it just takes up excess storage that is unnecessary.  Sounds great to stay true the source and not risk losing characters in conversion but the reality is we need to optimize storage and our load processes and that means not using unicode anytime we can avoid it.

Thoughts?

Comment: Why not embrace the unicode? Storage is cheap.

Comment: Data integrity versus the size of Unicode.  I will take data integrity every time.

Comment: First - if the data coming in from other sources is in Unicode, then you can't be certain you don't need Unicode. That said: If the problem is the data coming from new data sources, can the problem be fixed by changing the export process from those sources, to export non-Unicode data?

Comment: Actually storage is not cheap - its incredibly expensive in large quantities especially with SSDs. Doubling the cost of multimillion $ with of storage is only cheap if you're Trump. And every byte of extra storage means more memory and more I/O and more CPU = worse performance.

Comment: Yes the data can be changed from unicode and that is in fact what I am considering.  My approach was that like sp_BlitzErik but now I'm rethinking that due to the incredible negative consequences I'm now facing with implicit datatype conversions since some sources are unicode and some not and the excess storage is killing us not in storage cost but in performance pulling out of monster unicode tables with no added benefit other than the concept of keeping perfect value integrity. Btw...converting results in "?" for unicode characters in the data if there are any.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik Saxman is correct regarding storage costs. One must define the _type_ of storage when saying that it is cheap. _Non_-enterprise storage is cheap, but Enterprise / SAN storage is far from cheap: [Disk Is Cheap! ORLY?](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/data-modeling/71725/) ;-)

Comment: @Saxman regarding "_Btw...converting results in "?" for unicode characters in the data if there are any._": that all depends on where the conversion is happening. In SQL Server and some methods of doing this in .NET you could very well get Best-Fit translations to "equivalent" characters, if such a mapping exists for a particular character not in the target Code Page.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server with Table and Index Compression (Row, Page or Columnstore) NVarchar columns don't use two bytes per character.  They use [Unicode Compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/unicode-compression-implementation).

Here's an example:

```
use master 
go
drop database TestUnicodeCompression
go
create database TestUnicodeCompression

go
use TestUnicodeCompression
drop table if exists A
drop table if exists B
go
create table A(id int identity, a nvarchar(200) default cast(newid() as nvarchar(200) ))

create table B(id int identity, a varchar(200) default cast(newid() as varchar(200)))

go

with q as
(
  select top 1000000 row_number() over (order by (select null)) i
  from sys.objects o, sys.columns c, sys.columns c2
)
insert into A(A) select cast(newid() as varchar(200))
from q;

with q as
(
  select top 1000000 row_number() over (order by (select null)) i
  from sys.objects o, sys.columns c, sys.columns c2
)
insert into B(A) select cast(newid() as varchar(200))
from q;

go
alter table A rebuild with (data_compression=none)
alter table B rebuild with (data_compression=none)
go

select 'before compression' state,  
       cast( object_name(object_id) as varchar(10)) table_name, 
       used_page_count 
from sys.dm_db_partition_stats
where object_id in (object_id('A'), object_id('B'))

go

alter table A rebuild with (data_compression=page)
alter table B rebuild with (data_compression=page)

go

select 'after compression' state, 
        cast( object_name(object_id) as varchar(10)) table_name, 
        used_page_count 
from sys.dm_db_partition_stats
where object_id in (object_id('A'), object_id('B'))
```

outputs

```
(1000000 rows affected)

(1000000 rows affected)
state              table_name used_page_count
------------------ ---------- --------------------
before compression A          11114
before compression B          6581

(2 rows affected)

state             table_name used_page_count
----------------- ---------- --------------------
after compression A          6210
after compression B          6062

(2 rows affected)
```

Comment: Sounds like its saying it just does compression but still takes 2 bytes regardless instead of just 1 byte right?

Comment: Nope.  One byte per character for several commonly-used languages, per the doc link.

Comment: I tested this with 2 duplcicate tables with only difference using varchar verses nvarchar.  I compressed both using page compression.   Result after compression was still the same ratio...in other words, compression did not eliminate the extra space taken up by using nvarchar.

Comment: @Saxman added an example demonstrating the higher compression ratio for NVarchar data.

Comment: Thanks David, I ran above and tried throwing in some random characters and same result as you. I am re-doing my previous test which uses the Dynamics CRM Contact entity with over 8 million contacts and will provide results.

Comment: David, I have the contact entity as unicode page compressed. Used page count = 135335.  I create to script, changed all nvarchar to varchar, then did INSERT INTO CONTACT_VARCHARONLY
SELECT * FROM CONTACT.  Then did page compress.  Used page count for the CONTACT_VARCHARONLY table = 672200.  Once again, the nvarchar compressed was twice the size of the varchar only version of the table.  So with real data, it appears behave much differently than the artificial generation of data that you used.  Someone much smarter than me will know why this is.

Comment: I'm confused.  135335 < 672200.  Can you generate a repro with sample data that demonstrates significant size savings for compressed varchar storage?

Comment: Sorry cut/paste lost a digit...nvarchar used page count = 1353335.  Same table with varchar = 672200.  Do you have simple way to obfuscate customer data across > 460 columns?   And if I did "sample" data we could end up with what I suspect your example may have had - compression will mis-represent compression ratios for data that is artificially similar.  Note that this table when created gives this warning...Warning: The table "CONTACT" has been created, but its maximum row size exceeds the allowed maximum of 8060 bytes..

Answer (score 1):

My solution was 
 1) as RDFozz suggested, convert from unicode to non-unicode in the extract, 
 2) use Task Factory Advanced Derived Column component to change the datatype (since a simple datatype translation works in that component but does not with the SSIS provided data conversion or the derived column components - they both blow when finding non-ascii characters in data).  This is all then generated using BIML that throws all nchar/nvarchar, etc through the TF component.

The end result is significant savings in both storage and prevents current performance problems experienced with sources where we didn't do this.

My advice...it's all well and good in theory to keep unicode datatypes. But the reality is it comes at a significant cost and you should be able to justify it. Be sure the data integrity purity is needed or you are incurring significant unnecessary overhead.